# Which version of spectral clustering in sklearn library?

Tags: scikit-learn, spectral-clustering

Which version of spectral clustering is implemented in sklearn library? Is it **Shi, Malik** or **Ng, Jordan, Weiss** from [this tutorial](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.165.9323&rep=rep1&type=pdf)? In sklearn user guide, both versions are mentioned in [reference](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#spectral-clustering). From the source code, it is not trivial to understand what is implemented as the authors used some tricks for code optimization.

Comment: According to this page (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#spectral-embedding), it uses the Laplacian Eigenmaps algorithm; does this help?